# How to return nested dictionary to a Mako template in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

When I tried to return a nested dictionary to Mako template, it replaces single quotes with HTML code `&#39;` (I saw it in browser's source code).

In views:

```
@view_config(route_name='main', renderer='myproj:templates/main.mako')
def main_view(request):
    info = {'name': 'Some', 'age': 20}
    return {'info': info, 'country': 'Ukraine'}
```

In Mako:

```
<script type="text/javascript">func(${info})</script>
```

In browser's source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">func({&#39;name&#39;: &#39;Some&#39;, &#39;age&#39;: 20})</script>
```

How to avoid this escaping? (`renderer='json'` is not variant, because I need that dictionary in Mako)

Comment: I could probably answer this if you gave an example of what you were doing in both Python and Mako snippets.

Comment: I've edited my question with code examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Michael Merickel - see my edit, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mako is configured by default to escape strings. If you want to disable the filters this can be done via `|n`. Specifically `${info|n}`.

In your example, however, you are trying to pass a **python** dictionary to a **javascript** function. This obviously doesn't add up and you need to turn the python dict into something usable by javascript. What you actually want to do here is turn your python dict into a string which is then output with no filtering to your javascript code.

This could be prettied up, but the idea is that in python you do:

```
@view_config(route_name='main', renderer='myproj:templates/main.mako')
def main_view(request):
    info = json.dumps({'name': 'Some', 'age': 20})
    return {'info': info, 'country': 'Ukraine'}
```

and in mako you do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">func(${info|n})</script>
```

By default Pyramid sets mako to use the `h` filter, which escapes everything (the issue you're seeing). You can edit the default filters but it's not usually the greatest idea because of potential side-effects in other code. The other possibility is to rely on the dict's `__str__` implementation to yield valid javascript code. In this case you do not need to serialize anything, simply run `${info|str,n}` which (at least in this case) yields your desired result.

Comment: Yes, your answer is right, but maybe there is some easier way without dumping to json and escaping with `| n` in mako. Because I use mako in my Django project and there rendering a dictionary to mako works fine without json and escaping in mako. Thanks!

Comment: updated answer, I've looked at the django-mako implementation and it doesn't do anything special (neither does pyramid) for dicts. django-mako doesn't turn on escaping by default, which is dangerous for anyone who might be displaying input from users (XSS vulnerabilities).

Comment: it would be better to do :  `json.dumps({'name': 'Some', 'age': 20}).encode('string-escape')` ; if there is any text that contains a single-quote in the json payload, it will break javascript.